# Windows shortcut support for macOS Sierra

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

I recently have to work with both a mac and a windows PC. Because I have worked my whole life with PC, I'm used to work with default Windows shortcuts.
So I'm trying to get these shortcuts running on macOS, because I'm obviously too dumb for switching my typing behaviour between both systems.

My main focus are following shortcuts: Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-A, Pos1, End, Ctrl-left arrow, Ctrl-right arrow

I found the great software called "[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)" which should support all of these shortcuts. Unfortunately it is not working on macOS Sierra 
and the new "Karabiner Elements" does not support all functions I would need.

Does anyone know a good replacement for "Karabiner"? Or any other way to get the Windows shortcuts running on macOS Sierra?

Comment: Honestly, you will be better off long-term learning the difference rather than trying to force the Mac to behave like Windows. I've been working cross-platform for 25 years & I've found no better system than *'just work with it, not against it'.*

Comment: Totally agree with @Tetsujin here.  I came from Windows (on the Desktop, UNIX on the server) background and I still use 3 platforms (Mac, Windows, BSD) almost daily.  After a little while, you easily switch from Windows to Mac shortcuts and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

## Swapping <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>

### NOTE: If doing the other keys, do this last. You'll have to do it again on the virtual keyboard otherwise.

1. Go into System Preferences.

[image: System Preferences Screenshot.]

2. Go into Keyboard.

[image: System Preferences Screenshot with Keyboard highlighted.]

3. Click on "Modifier Keys…"

[image: System Preferences Screenshot with Modifier Keys clicked.]

4. Click on the menu adjacent to "Command (⌘) Key".

[image: Modifier Keys menu]

5. This menu should show up. Just remap <kbd>Control</kbd> to <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>, and vice versa.

## Non- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> / <kbd>Control</kbd> Keys

Quite frankly, a large number of apps already support the Windows keybindings, and Mission Control makes <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> a small nightmare. But, if you must, this is how you do it.

In Karabiner-Elements, as shown by Clemsam, these combos are what you should map various keys to:

<kbd>Home (Pos1)</kbd>: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

<kbd>End</kbd>: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>: <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>: <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

The JSON to do that is the following:

```
{
  "title": "Most Windows Behavior.",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Change Home key to Windows behavior.",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "home",
            "modifiers": {
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_arrow", "modifiers": ["fn", "left_control"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Change End key to Windows behavior",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "end",
            "modifiers": {
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "right_arrow", "modifiers": ["fn", "left_control"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Change Control+Left Arrow to Windows behavior.",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "right_arrow",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": ["left_control"],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_arrow",
              "modifiers": ["left_alt"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Change Control+Right Arrow key to Windows behavior.",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "right_arrow",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "left_control"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "right_arrow", "modifiers": ["left_alt", "right_arrow"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 0):

Karabiner Elements easily supports such simple re-mappings, though only as pre-fabricated "Complex Modifications", downloadable from the app's site.

If your specific needs aren't met there, you'd have to expand Karabiner's

`~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json` yourself (simply: BBEdit / TextEdit), like this:

Example for Ctrl-C to Cmd-C:

```
{"Description": "Ctrl-C to Cmd-C, next and last re-mapping", 
 "manipulators": [
      { "from": {"key_code": "c",
                 "modifiers": {   "mandatory": ["left_control"] } },
        "to": [ {"key_code": "c", "modifiers": ["left_command"] } ],
        "type": "basic"
                                              },
      {  NOT REAL CODE: next re-mapping HERE  },
      {  NOT REAL CODE: last re-mapping HERE  }
                 ]
}
```

… your other re-mappings accordingly.

(Notice: "commas" after a bracket are ONLY needed (and allowed!) if other elements/re-mappings follow!)