# How can I have Windows keymapping on my Macbook, CTRL+C, CTRL+V

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

I have a Macbook pro 2016, I am a Linux user at home and I am used to CTRL+C, CTRL+X, CTRL+V kind of key mapping for my copy, cut and paste actions. I have set up keyboard modifier as below

[image]

I also have added additional keyboard shortcut overrides

[image]

But still some controls like copy paste does not work correctly from firefox or specifically from text fields.

Is there any thing I can do to make it streamlined ?

There are apps I have issues with. Visual Studio Code, Browser input fields, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work correctly"? What is "correctly" for you and how does the way it works not meet your expectations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my Windows keyboard shortcuts work on a Mac, exactly how they do on Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299361/how-can-i-make-my-windows-keyboard-shortcuts-work-on-a-mac-exactly-how-they-do)

Comment: Did you check that the apps that don’t work spell those menu items the exact same way, not `Copy...` or anything like that? If they are spelled the same, try making a new set of shortcuts just for one of those apps. Ideally, try w/ Ctrl-C, etc, first, but also try w/ something else definitely unused by the app, just to make sure the app honors those shortcuts at all, maybe it’s something that apps can ignore.

Answer (score 1):

If you got at least MacOS Sierra on your MacBook you might use Karabiner Elements. If there is no suitable set of "Complex Modifications" importable for your case on their site, you'd have to manually edit

```
~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json
```

with e.g. BBEdit (better make a backup copy before you start!).
Doing so you'd have to go to:

```json
"rules": [ /*...*/ ]
```

Here is an example from [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337324/how-to-map-ctrl-left-arrow-to-home-with-karabiner-elements) asked here:

```json
{
  "Description": "Ctrl-C to Cmd-C, next and last re-mapping",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "from": {
        "key_code": "c",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_control"] 
        }
      },
      "to": [{
        "key_code": "c",
        "modifiers": ["left_command"] 
      }],
      "type": "basic"
    }
  ]
}
```

I suppose this should work with any app as the key code is altered low level.