# How to map CTRL + Left Arrow to Home with Karabiner-Elements

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

I'm using Karabiner-Elements to map some keys with an external PC keyboard. I'd like to map CTRL + Left Arrow to Home and CTRL + Right Arrow to End. Is it possible to do this?

There's a complex rule for download that maps SHIFT + Left Arrow to End but I'm using CTRL.

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why won't COMMAND left and right arrow do? They already do the same as home and end, respectively

Comment: Cmd/arrow isn't universal for mapping the 'page' keys, but Fn/Arrow is. [btw, Ctrl/arrow is for switching Spaces by default, so you might also have to switch that off to do what you're aiming for]

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to manually edit  ~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json with e.g. BBEdit or TextEdit (better make a backup copy before you start!).

Be aware: your re-mapping would de-activate Apple's Spaces-switching feature!

Anyway, doing so you'd have to go to

```
"rules": [
```

and (assuming you mean the *right* control key) add s.th. like:

```
"rules": [
    {  "description": "Call it whatever you like…",
       "manipulators": [ {
                "type": "basic",
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "left_arrow",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "mandatory": [
                            "right_control"
                        ]
                    }
              },
              "to": [
                  {
                      "key_code": "home"
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "type": "basic",
              "from": {
                  "key_code": "right_arrow",
                  "modifiers": {
                      "mandatory": [
                           "right_control"
                      ]
                  }
              },
              "to": [
                  {
                      "key_code": "end"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
]
```

Be aware that the right order and correct corresponding of open and closed brackets of both types is essential!
(As far as I can see there is no way to debug this behaviour; maybe apart from watching Karabiner-Element's open Window while saving the json-file. Your choice of editor can help though, even BBEdit can identify pairs of brackets …)

If what you did is correct, the new behaviour will work *instantaneously* once you saved the file!

So, if yours is the only Complex Modification, the closing "comma" must NOT be used here … but if you add yours to all previous ones this "comma" must instead be placed in front of your code (meaning: behind the last rule's finishing bracket.
… a bit tricky, this all.