# Swap or remap Cmd+Tab to Ctrl+Tab Optional Shift Only

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

**Please read my answer and bmike's comment before voting to close.** Someone is going to come along and say I should just learn Mac shortcuts, but I must say I use Chromebooks, Windows, & Linux boxes and they all put the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> in the bottom left and right hand corner of the computer.  I'm sorry but changing one operating system is way easier then changing the other three (especially considering the speed lag of some softwares.)

To alleviate the most common keyboard shortcuts, I have the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> mapped to the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on my Apple computer.  And have switched the right <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Opt</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) on the right hand side.  I then switched <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> again in iTerm (a very well made application).

Now unfortunately <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> no longer works to switch between browser tabs.  Well, tabs in any application actually.

I would like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I am on El Captain using Karabiner Elements and would prefer to stay away from Karabiner (the older version).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my Windows keyboard shortcuts work on a Mac, exactly how they do on Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299361/how-can-i-make-my-windows-keyboard-shortcuts-work-on-a-mac-exactly-how-they-do)

Comment: @Allan I have remapped manually all the shortcuts in the answer above.  I just can't do the Cmd+Tab = Ctrl+Tab myself.  This is about a specific shortcut.  I would like to add that is not answer at all(mac is the outlier here.)

Comment: Yes. Let’s leave this open since it’s super interesting how to only remap these two combinations and not just swap all instances of command with control. The link to the similar question is solid and should remain as they are close cousins indeed.

Comment: @bmike for those that type on Dvorak cmd QWERTY is some desire to do it the way I have listed.  I should have concluded that with the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the JSON to remap these keys only.

https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=swap%20command%20control%20shift%20with%20optional%20shift

If you save the following as a HTML file onto the Desktop and save the t.json above as a `t.json` file it should let you add as a modification.

```
<script>
var t = document.location.href.split('/');
t.pop();
t.push('t.json');
t.shift();
t.shift();
t.shift();
var url = 'karabiner://karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/import?url=file%3A%2F%2F%2F'+encodeURIComponent(t.join('/'));


document.write('<a href="'+url+'">Add Modification</a>');

</script>
```

Comment: For those new to Karabiner and MacOS like myself: Save the JSON file under ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications and then it will be automatically imported when adding a rule under the complex modifications tab.

Comment: ok, this is nice, but WHERE are you supposed to paste this into?

Comment: @ahnbizcad check the comment above.  https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/location/   go to terminal and type `cd ~/.config/karabiner/assets/`

Comment: @ahnbizcad then type `pwd` and enter to get path of file