# Assigning a "Skip Word" Shortcut in OS Ventura

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

This is my first Mac, and there have been quite a few positives since converting. However, one thing that has been bothering me comes when typing. In short,

**How do I reassign option+ -> to control + -> such that hitting that combination will skip to the next word when editing text??**

It's physically annoying to hit option and I often switch between Windows and Mac machines and there was nothing apparent to me in the Keyboard Shortcut settings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I essentially made it so my Macbook Pro keyboard operated like a Windows keyboard in regards to navigating words in a text editor

1. Navigate to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Mission Control in left -> Expand Mission Control in right pane -> uncheck
   *Move left a space* and *Move right a space*
3. Install Karabiner (free)
4. Under **Simple Modifications** Swap *fn* with *left_control*
5. Under **Complex Modifications** select *Add Rule*
6. Select *Import more Rules from the Internet*
7. Download and add all rules from **Windows-like word movement selection/deletion**

It's now a lot less frustrating coming from a Windows computer, and quite frankly, more ergonomic to use the bottom left most key instead or option to navigate words

Answer (score 0):

> This is my first Mac, and there have been quite a few positives since converting [from Windows]

The keyboard navigation short cuts are based on Emacs key bindings and this has been the case since the very beginnings of macOS.

→ [Why emacs commands work everywhere on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378477/why-emacs-commands-work-everywhere-on-macos/378543#378543)

The [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Line-Editing) and
[Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Movement) shells (available for macOS, FreeBSD, Linux, Solaris etc.) uses Emacs bindings.  It's best to become familiar with these rather than adapt a Unix operating system to act like Windows.

Below is an abbreviated list of common navigation  shortcuts

| Entity | Backward | Forward |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Character | <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> | <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> |
| Word | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> |
| Line | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> |
| Sentence | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> |
| Go to beg/end of line | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> |
| Page | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> | <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> |

GNU provides an excellent [Quick Reference card](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf) with these and the rest of the standard keybindings.  Remember that <kbd>◆ Meta</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>.

> It's physically annoying to hit option and I often switch between Windows and Mac machines

This is common for new users coming from a Windows world where they now live in both worlds.  Don't try to reassign one to work like the other.  Apps (both native and 3rd party) [develop with the expectations that keyboard shortcuts are respected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/299363/119271).  The adjustment period to be able to switch between the two environments is shorter than most people expect.

I personally use macOS, Windows, and FreeBSD with a little Linux thrown in for good measure.  It's almost seamless switching between all three and if it took me a month to become proficient I would genuinely be surprised.